# Gracefully handle server unavailability, globally, in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've created an interceptor in my Angular app that gracefully handles 500 errors from the server.

I'd also like to account for the case that the server is unreachable entirely, and I'd like to do this on an application-wide basis.

If it's helpful, here's the interceptor I have now (ES6):

```
'use strict';

var FVInterceptor = $q => {

  var failureCallback = rejection => {
    if (rejection.status === 500) {
      alert('Sorry, something went wrong. Please try again later.');
    }
    return $q.reject(rejection);
  };

  return {
    'request':       config => config,
    'response':      config => config,
    'requestError':  failureCallback,
    'responseError': failureCallback,
  };
};

FVInterceptor.$inject = ['$q'];

export default FVInterceptor;
```

Thanks.

Comment: have you set up a timeout in defaults? Also status 0 for no internet connection.

Comment: read here [offline-mode](http://angularts.com/offline-mode/), you would need to modify solution to check status codes as well